# Autostart Firefox on CentOS 6 kiosk system with Gnome Display Manager + Openmotif Window Manager

Tags: centos, gnome, xorg

I am in process of creating kiosk system on CentOS 6.9 minimal install with Gnome Display Manager (gdm) and Openmotif Window Manager (mwm) and Firefox web browser.

I have connected gdm to mwm by installing xorg-x11-xinit-session packet and creating ~/.Xcients file with single line

```
/usr/bin/mwm
```

like described in question https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1339013

Now after I enter my credentials on Gnome Display Manager - Openmotif Window Manager launches

Now my task is to start Firefox (preferably in full screen) when Openmotif Window Manager launches

I can successfully start Firefox if I pin it to Openmotif right click menu by changing Openmotif configuration file /etc/X11/mwm/system.mwmrc but I need that Firefox will start automatically

If I change ~/.Xcients file like this

```
/usr/bin/mwm
firefox
```

or like this

```
/usr/bin/mwm
/usr/bin/firefox
```

then Openmotif start up successfully, but firefox do not

Please tell me how can I start Firefox (prerably in Full screen mode) after Openmotif Window Manager launches or tell me where to dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send mwm to background before starting firefox. Change your script to this:

```
/usr/bin/mwm &
sleep 20 # to let mwm start fully
/usr/bin/firefox
```